# GoogleMaps API v3 - Trigger event from link in Infowindow

Tags: maps

I have a listener for a right-click context menu that allows me to perform actions specific to that particular infowindow. For instance, here is my code that opens and fills a directions panel:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(contextMenu, 'menu_item_selected', function(latLng, eventName){
                    switch(eventName){
                        case 'directions_from_click':
                            showDirections();
                            geocoder.geocode({latLng: latLng}, function(results, status) {
                              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                if (results[0]) {
                                  fAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
                                  $('#start').val(fAddress);
                                  $('#panelWrapper').focus();
                                }
                              }
                            });
                            $('#panelWrapper').focus();
                            break;
                        case 'directions_to_click':
                            showDirections();
                            geocoder.geocode({latLng: latLng}, function(results, status) {
                                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    if (results[0]) {
                                      fAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
                                      $('#end').val(fAddress);
                                      $('#panelWrapper').focus();
                                    }
                                  }
                                });
                            $('#panelWrapper').focus();
                            break;
                    }

                });
```

In addition to the right-click context menu, I'd also like to have a link in the infowindow that performs the same action onclick:

```
<a class="fromLink">Directions from here</a>
```

How do I add a listener for this link to perform something similar to my context menu? I've been experimenting with the addDomListener function, but I'm not sure if that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the API, so I just ended up passing in LatLng via an onclick event into a function to fill in the direction input. Rather ugly, but sort of like this:

```
function addMessageMarker(marker, addlInfo){

    var position = String(marker.getPosition());
    var fromLink = '<a class="infoLink" onClick="getFrom(&quot;' + position +  '&quot;)">Directions from here</a> - '; 
    ... //bunch of other stuff
}
function getFrom(position) {
                    showDirections();
                    //Convert the string value into a latLng
                    var latLng = position.replace("(","");
                    latLng = latLng.replace(")","");
                    latLng = latLng.replace(" ","");
                    latLngArr = latLng.split(",");
                    lat = parseFloat(latLngArr[0]);
                    lng = parseFloat(latLngArr[1]);

                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

                    geocoder.geocode({latLng: latLng}, function(results, status) {
                      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                      fAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
                      $('#start').val(fAddress);

                        }
                      }
                    });
                    $('#panelWrapper').focus();
                }
```